# Rails get image from download link without saving image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image

Given a download link:

`http://files.parsetfss.com/54213c13-6c9c-4c87-ad62-b03471f4a879/tfss-17095044-922e-4b24-a361-2763f1981a13-profile.jpg`

I'd like to display the image from the link without having to save it to a file. My use case would be display images from the links and there could be hundreds of links so it wouldn't be feasible to save each image to disk.

Comment: The normal way to "display an image" is the `<img>` tag. Assuming the URL you are using is accessible via a web browser, then `<img src="http://files.parsetfss.com/54213c13-6c9c-4c87-ad62-b03471f4a879/tfss-17095044-922e-4b24-a361-2763f1981a13-profile.jpg" alt="alternate image text" />` would render the image in your user's browser.

Comment: You're asking for your Ruby application to behave as a proxy for binary data. While it's certainly possible, you would probably be better served by setting up a proxy server (see: nginx).

Comment: @GSP I tried the img tag but it returns a `403 Forbidden` error. If I just paste the link in a browser, it'll download the image.

Answer (score 2):

Change the MIME type to `image/jpeg`. Your current `content-type` is `application/octet-stream` which says the browser to download the file.

If you have a PNG you have use the MIME type `image/png`. Just google for "MIME types" if you have more file types.

But as @GSP already said, if you want to show the image to a normal user it would be better to use the `<img>` HTML tag to embed it into your website.

Comment: But the url isn't exactly an image link, if you open the link in a browser, it will automatically download the image.

Comment: Of course is it an image link. It has just the wrong MIME type which tells the browser to download the image instead of showing it directly in the browser. Normally the web server should handle this by itself. As it looks like you are using Amazon S3. Take a look into the S3 config. If you process the images, check also the processing config. Maybe there is a mistake while the image is processed and something gets broken.

Comment: I can't specify the MIME type. I am not the one hosting the image. I just have the url to it

Comment: @VincentLe Which is why the appropriate action is to proxy it and serve it yourself.